# How to Edit R script inserted in PowerBI from data source setings

Tags: r, powerbi

i have created a few tables in Power Bi using R script. This R script connects to MS SQL server to fetch data.
Later it does transformation and checks normality.
Post checking normality it populates the new transformed data in Power Bi.

TO insert these tables in Power-bi i directly pasted the entire R script in power-bi in data sources setting.

Now i have realized i have done some minor mistake in creating a table and need to modify the existing R script and eliminate the old script from the power Bi. But not able to do so from power Bi data source setting. Can someone please help.

Comment: Showing what you have done, rather than saying "i have done some minor mistake" might enable people to answer this question.

Comment: I understand that this question is about the possibility to have the R script sourced to Power BI from an external file so that when you update it in e.g. RStudio it gets updated in Power BI. As far as I know, it is not available at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after researching and experimenting I found out that we can do that by going in the advanced editor in power query mode and simply paste the newly edited script which is already tried and tested in R programming language.

Thanks a lot for your support